# Navigate from a custom Visualforce button, to a LWC page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, lightning-web-components

Say I have a custom VisualForce Button in an account list view,

Is it possible once clicked on that custom button, to be redirected to a LWC page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently directly navigating to LWC is not possible. So the workaround is to embed the lwc component inside a lightning aura component with interface lightning:isUrlAddressable and navigate to the aura component from visualforce.